# SpriteMask in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: 1]

There are many identical objects, each of which has a child.
The child object must not appear outside of the parent. I do this using SpriteMask, but with this approach, the child object sees within the boundaries of someone else's parent, as in the screenshot

Comment: Look at this [link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1699002/mask-a-sprite-with-multiple-spritemasks.html#:~:text=Mask%20a%20Sprite%20with%20multiple%20SpriteMasks%3F%20-%20Unity,property%20on%20SpriteRenderer%20component%20to%20Visible%20Outside%20Mask.)

Comment: Welcome! As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587) Can you please [edit] to pose a clear, precise question? Maybe your question can be inferred, but this whole site is based on a framework of Q&A, so for the good of the framework, please ask a question. You can see [ask] for guidance.